# Maven Dependency & Spring - Overwrite application context from dependency war

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml

I manage to add dependency ProjectWeb project into SchedulerWeb project. Successful run the web that has been develop in ProjectWeb project through SchedulerWeb package.

However, i cannot inject bean in SchedulerWeb project. When I start instance of SchedulerWeb, it not scan SchedulerWeb annotation.

```
ProjectWeb
  - src/main/java.....
  - src/main/resource
    - applicationContext.xml
      - <context:component-scan base-package="com.myprojectWEB.service" />



SchedulerWeb
  - src/main/java.../scheduler
    - mainScheduler.java 
  - src/main/resource
    - applicationContext.xml
      - <context:component-scan base-package="com.myprojectWEB.service" />
      - <context:component-scan base-package="com.myprojectWEB.scheduler" />
```

in com.myprojectWEB.scheduler i create one class and the code is per below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class Main {
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 500)
    public void executeEveryOneMin() {
        System.out.println("Run Job " + new Date());
    }
}
```

So how i want the SchedulerWeb will call their own applicationcontext.xml?

** i put the scheduler in projectWEB is working fine but not in SchedulerWeb.

Any advice?